# QMediaPlayer stream play dose not work in windows

Tags: qt, streaming, qmediaplayer

I want to play stream video.

The server was configured using ffserver.

ffplay working fine

```
ffplay http://192.168.0.122:8090/camera2.mjpeg
```

OpenCV Examples is wokring fine.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture("http://192.168.0.122:8090/camera2.mjpeg");
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {

        return -1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> frame;

        imshow("video", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

But in Qt VideoPlayer example is notworking.

It does not work only on Windows.

It works fine on Ubuntu.

In VideoWidget, it was modified as follows.

```
void VideoPlayer::openFile()
{
#if 0
    QFileDialog fileDialog(this);
    fileDialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptOpen);
    fileDialog.setWindowTitle(tr("Open Movie"));
    QStringList supportedMimeTypes = m_mediaPlayer->supportedMimeTypes();
    if (!supportedMimeTypes.isEmpty())
        fileDialog.setMimeTypeFilters(supportedMimeTypes);
    fileDialog.setDirectory(QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::MoviesLocation).value(0, QDir::homePath()));
    if (fileDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        setUrl(fileDialog.selectedUrls().constFirst());
#endif
    setUrl(QUrl("http://192.168.0.122:8090/camera2.mjpeg"));
}
```

qmediaplayer object does not have a valid service.

is need a special library in Windows?
Let me know what is wrong for me.

PS.

1. file is working
2. mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback); is same result

Comment: QMediaPlayer depends on the underlaying multimedia framework (ffmpeg, gstreamer, ...) to be able to handle multimedia files. Maybe if your Qt was build with ffmpeg support this could work, otherwise, MJPEG is not a really popular format for video files. It is for streaming though! But that's a different thing.